# Is there a way to speed up computer turn movement in Troy Total War Saga?

Tags: troy-total-war

In Troy Total War Saga is there a way to speed up the campaign movement by AI armies, so that they computer controlled armies and agents moved at a faster pace?

I can see this option exists for the player's armies (default key is `R`), although this doesn't seem to translate to faster AI movement speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, there is.**

In the upper right corner of the screen, there's a button named "Camera Settings".

[image: Screenshot showing Camera Settings window]

When you click on it, you'll see a window with camera settings for different factions. From left to right, they are:

- Your faction
- Individual factions (you can cycle through each faction currently in the game, even if you haven't encountered them)
- Allied factions
- Enemy factions
- Neutral factions

There are a lot of factions, so I recommend setting "Allied factions", "Enemy factions", and "Neutral factions" instead.

"Camera" determines the height of the camera.

What you're interested in, is "Animation speed", which determines how fast the units of different factions are animated on the Campaign map.

The options for "Animation speed" are:

- Normal (default)
- Fast
- Fastest